# Group Theory Lemma Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $(G,*)$ and $(H,\circ)$ are groups and $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism

Prove $f(a^n)=f(a)^n$  $ \forall a\in G, n\in \Bbb{Z}$ . I can't think of smart ways to manipulate  the properties of the homomorphism to prove the lemma. Please help.

Comment: It would have been better if you had posted your ideas. As you can see the solution if very trivial. Looking at the definition of group homomorphism is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use induction on $n$.

Base case: $n = 1$ is clear, since $f(a)^1 = f(a^1)$.

Inductive step: Suppose $f(a)^n = f (a^n)$.

We want to show that $f(a)^{n+1} = f(a^{n+1})$.

Since $f$ is a homomorphism $f(a^{n+1}) = f(a a^n) = f(a) f(a^n) = f(a)f(a)^n = f(a)^{n+1}$. Hence $f(a^{n+1}) = f(a)^{n+1}. \text{ } \Box$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is a homomorphism,
\begin{equation}
f(a\ast b)=f(a)\circ f(b) \tag{1}
\end{equation} for all $a, b\in G$. In particular this holds when $a=b$, which gives $f(a^2)=f(a)\circ f(a)=f(a)^2$. So we just proved $f(a^2)=f(a)^2$. Now apply the formula (1) to $a$ and $b=a^2$ to get
$$
f(a^3)=f(a\ast a^2)\overset{(1)}{=}f(a)\circ f(a^2) = f(a) \circ f(a)^2 = f(a)^3
$$
So $f(a^3)=f(a)^3$. Do you see how to use induction to prove the claim for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

After you are done with this, you can use the formula $f(a)f(a^{-1})=1$ to get $f(a^{-1})=f(a)^{-1}$, which will allow you to deal with $f(a)^{n}$ for $n<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Induction on $n$, the case $n=0$ being dealt with by the fact that $x^0 = 1$ in any group and that any group morphism sends $1$ to $1$, and the induction step being dealt with the morphism property $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in G$. With this, you show the result for $n\in\mathbf{N}$. To pass to $\mathbf{Z}$, use that $f(a^{-1}) = f(a)^{-1}$ because $1 = f(aa^{-1})$ and use the previous case to conclude.